# Problem with Heroku_Accounts and Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have been pushing projects to Heroku without any issues.  Just installed the Heroku_Accounts plugin (which I am excited to use!).  Now I am having the following problem when I push to heroku:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 1338, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1103/1103), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1338/1338), 1.27 MiB, done.
Total 1338 (delta 694), reused 417 (delta 182)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile
       Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
       Installing rails_log_stdout... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       Using --without development:test
       Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
       Installing rake (0.9.2) 
       Installing abstract (1.0.0) 
       Installing activesupport (3.0.4) 
       Installing builder (2.1.2) 
       Installing i18n (0.6.0) 
       Installing activemodel (3.0.4) 
       Installing erubis (2.6.6) 
       Installing rack (1.2.3) 
       Installing rack-mount (0.6.14) 
       Installing rack-test (0.5.7) 
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.29) 
       Installing actionpack (3.0.4) 
       Installing mime-types (1.16) 
       Installing polyglot (0.3.1) 
       Installing treetop (1.4.9) 
       Installing mail (2.2.19) 
       Installing actionmailer (3.0.4) 
       Installing arel (2.0.10) 
       Installing activerecord (3.0.4) 
       Installing activeresource (3.0.4) 
       Installing braintree (2.6.1) 
       Installing client_side_validations (3.0.4) 
       Installing columnize (0.3.4) 
       Installing gravatar_image_tag (1.0.0.pre2) 
       Installing rbx-require-relative (0.0.5) /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:164:in `install': rbx-require-relative requires Ruby version ~> 1.8.7. (Gem::InstallError)
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/source.rb:95:in `install'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `block in run'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in `install'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
       FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

To git@heroku.com:cold-warrior-388.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:cold-warrior-388.git'
daniel-kents-macbook-pro:steepr Daniel$
```

Here are my remote urls:

```
$ git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:cold-warrior-388.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:cold-warrior-388.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:steepr.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:steepr.git (push)
```

Here is my .ssh/config

```
# default 

Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /Users/Daniel/.ssh/id_rsa

# steepr

Host github-steepr
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /Users/Daniel/.ssh/steepr.id_rsa.pub

Host heroku.steepr
  HostName heroku.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity.heroku.steepr
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host heroku.personal
  HostName heroku.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity.heroku.personal
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Like I said, was pushing to heroku fine before adding Heroku_Accounts.  Does the plugin do something to Bundler? to my gems?

THank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue by commenting out `gem 'Ruby-debug'`.  This was something I read elsewhere on Stackoverflow, but when I tried it the first time it didn't work.  I am not sure what I did wrong the first time, but if you try this approach, make sure you:

(1) `bundle install`

(2) commit and push to git

(3) THEN push to heroku

Good Luck!

@thatdankent